# Rollback not working in laravel multiple database in 5.2

Tags: laravel, commit, rollback

Rollback not working in laravel multiple database in 5.2. What can i do? please help me. Advance thanks.

```
public function TestingRegistration(){

    $now=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $faculty_user_account=array(
                'user_id' =>'466297',
                'name' => 'Hello',
                );
        \DB::beginTransaction();
            try{
$save_registration=\DB::table('users')->insert($faculty_user_account);
                $view2= \DB::connection('mysql_2')->table('users')->insert($faculty_user_account);
                $view3 = \DB::connection('mysql_3')->table('users')->insert($faculty_user_account);
                \DB::commit();        
                return \Redirect::back()->with('message',"Faculty Registration Successfull!"); 
            }catch(\Exception $e){
                \DB::rollback();
                $message = "Message : ".$e->getMessage().", File : ".$e->getFile().", Line : ".$e->getLine();

                return \Redirect::back()->with('errormessage',$message); 
            }
    }
```

Comment: You havn't started or rollbacked any transactions for the other databases, only the default one. Call beginTransaction, commit and rollback on all the connections.

Comment: I believe my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59873297/10539212) answer will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do transaction is to use it as a callback, this way it will be handle it automatically for you.

```
public function TestingRegistration(){

    $now = \Carbon::now(); // Where is this use? 

    $faculty_user_account = [
        'user_id' => '466297',
        'name' => 'Hello',
    ];

    $success = \DB::transaction(function () use ($faculty_user_account) {
        $save_registration = \DB::table('users')->insert($faculty_user_account);
        $view2 = \DB::connection('mysql_2')->table('users')->insert($faculty_user_account);
        $view3 = \DB::connection('mysql_3')->table('users')->insert($faculty_user_account);

        return (bool) $view2 && $view3;
    });

    if (! $success) {

        return \Redirect::back()->with('errormessage', 'Unable to save.'); 
    }

    return \Redirect::back()->with('message',"Faculty Registration Successfull!"); 
}
```

PS: I can't remember what insert returns, let me check later to make sure it can be use like that for testing success.