# Laravel DB::rollback() doesn't work for transaction processes

Tags: database, laravel, transactions, laravel-5.5

First off my engine is innoDB and I already tried the following on mySQL:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO `tbl_users`(...) VALUES (...)
ROLLBACK();
```

And it works fine, meaning the problem wasn't in my mysql config.

But when I tried this on my Laravel Model:

```
public static function addNew($request, $department_id) {

    $result = array();

    $now = Carbon::now();

    DB::beginTransaction();

    //Checking for existing Order to set appropriate starting ID
    $result = DB::select("
        SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS 'count'
        FROM `tbl_consignmentorders`
    ")[0];

    if($result->count == 0){
        DB::update("ALTER TABLE `tbl_consignmentorders` AUTO_INCREMENT = 70000000001;");
    }

    try {
        //INSERT
        DB::insert("
            INSERT INTO `tbl_consignmentorders`
            (`from`, `to`, `status`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) 
            VALUES 
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
            [
                $department_id,
                strtoupper($request->input('supplier')),
                'PENDING',
                $now,
                $now
            ]
        );
        //GET THE LAST ID INSERTED, NEEDED FOR NEXT INSERT
        $last_id = DB::select("
            SELECT 
                LAST_INSERT_ID() AS 'id'
            FROM `tbl_consignmentorders`;"
        )[0]->id;

        //CONSTRUCTING QUERY STRING FOR VALUES
        $values = '';
        $count = 0;
        foreach($request->input('item_id') as $item) {
            $values .= ',(' . $request->input('quantity')[$count] . ', ' . $last_id . ', ' . $item . ', ' . $request->input('item_price_id')[$count] . ' )';
            $count++;
        }
        $values[0] = ' ';

        //INSERT TO DETAILS
        DB::insert("
            INSERT INTO `tbl_consignmentorderdetails`
            (`quantity`, `order_id`, `item_id`, `item_price_id`) 
            VALUES 
            $values;"
        );

        //INSERT TO TRANSACTION AUDIT
        DB::insert("
            INSERT INTO `tbl_transactions`
            (`type`, `reference_id`, `department_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) 
            VALUES 
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
            [
                'CONSIGNMENT ORDER',
                $last_id,
                $department_id,
                $now,
                $now
            ]
        );

        //COMMIT NOTHING FAILS
        DB::commit();
        $result = true;

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        //ROLLBACK SOMETHING IS WRONG
        DB::rollback();
        $result = $e->getMessage();
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Now the above code works fine when successful, now to generate error, I will deliberately change this part of code:

```
    //GET THE LAST ID INSERTED, NEEDED FOR NEXT INSERT
    $last_id = DB::select("
        SELECT 
            LAST_INSERT_ID() AS 'id'
        FROM `tbl_consignmentorders`;"
    )[0]; //<--- I removed the ->id to return the whole object causing object to string error on the next query
```

Now as expected it goes to the catch block to pass the error message but, the queries executed before the error is still present in the database where it should not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake,

I use `DB::rollback();` instead of `DB::rollBack();` with capital B

Answer (score 6):

If your system use multiple database configs, you need to do something like this

```
DB::connection('database_config_2')->beginTransaction();
DB::connection('database_config_2')->rollback();
DB::connection('database_config_2')->commit();
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

The issue most people have with `DB::rollback` not working is that they do not start a `DB::transaction` function first!

`DB::rollback` only works when a transaction has been started

A transaction can be started in two ways:

1. Using the DB::transaction function inside your method

   ```
   DB::transaction(function () {
       DB::table('users')->update(['votes' => 1]);

       DB::table('posts')->delete();
   });
   ```
2. By manually starting a transaction at the beginning of a method and probably when a call to an external API fails, you call the DB::rollback() method

   ```
   DB::beginTransaction();

   DB::rollBack();
   ```